# dataframe in R: lookup multiple strings in a cell that are separated by a comma

Tags: r, string, dataframe, lookup, strsplit

Suppose each row in a column(letter_strings) has a variable number of strings separated by a comma. For example:

```
letter_strings

abc, def, ghi, jkl 
mno, pqr
stu, vw, xyz
```

I would like to lookup each string in a dataframe:

```
letter_strings code

abc YES
def NO
ghi MAYBE
jkl SURE
mno PERHAPS
pqr ALWAYS
stu NEVER
vw NOGO
xyz ABSENT
```

and obtain the following corresponding rows, in an additional column

```
YES, NO, MAYBE, SURE
PERHAPS, ALWAYS
NEVER, NOGO, ABSENT
```

Is this possible in R, I don't really know how to tackle this problem...

Thanks in advance!

W

Comment: Please provide a `dput` of your data in the body of your question. It will be helpful to determine the actual structure of the data that you are working with. If it is large, then `dput(head(dat, 10))` or so should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

**1) gusbfn**

`gsubfn` is like `gsub` except it looks up the matches to the regular expression (here defined to be `"\\w+"`, i.e. a sequence of word characters) in the names of the lookup list, `lookup`, replacing the names in the target string with their values in `lookup`.

```
library(gsubfn)

lookup <- with(DF2, as.list(setNames(code, letter_strings)))
transform(DF1, codes = gsubfn("\\w+", lookup, letter_strings))
```

giving:

```
      letter_strings                codes
1 abc, def, ghi, jkl YES, NO, MAYBE, SURE
2           mno, pqr      PERHAPS, ALWAYS
3       stu, vw, xyz  NEVER, NOGO, ABSENT
```

**2) dplyr/tidyr**  Convert DF1 to long form, join it with DF2 and then reshape it back to the original form:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF1 %>% 
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
    separate_rows(letter_strings) %>% 
    left_join(DF2) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(letter_string = toString(letter_strings), codes = toString(code)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(-id)
```

giving:

```
Joining, by = "letter_strings"
# A tibble: 3 x 2
       letter_string                codes
               <chr>                <chr>
1 abc, def, ghi, jkl YES, NO, MAYBE, SURE
2           mno, pqr      PERHAPS, ALWAYS
3       stu, vw, xyz  NEVER, NOGO, ABSENT
```

**3) strsplit/merge/aggregate**  Use `strsplit` to split the strings in `DF1` and `stack` that into long form `st`.  Then `merge` that with `DF2` and `aggregate` back to the original form.  No packages are used.

```
s <- strsplit(DF1$letter_strings, ", ")
st <- stack(setNames(s, seq_along(s)))
m <- merge(st, DF2, by = 1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
aggregate(. ~ ind, m, toString)[-1]
```

giving:

```
              values                 code
1 abc, def, ghi, jkl YES, NO, MAYBE, SURE
2           mno, pqr      PERHAPS, ALWAYS
3       stu, vw, xyz  NEVER, NOGO, ABSENT
```

**3a) magrittr** This could be expressed using magrittr:

```
library(magrittr)

DF1 %>%
    "$"("letter_strings") %>%
    strsplit(", ") %>%
    setNames(seq_along(.)) %>%
    stack %>%
    merge(DF2, by = 1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE) %>%
    aggregate(. ~ ind, ., toString) %>%
    "["(-1)


s <- stack(setNames(strsplit(DF1$letter_strings, ", "), 1:nrow(DF1)))
m <- merge(s, DF2, by = 1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
aggregate(. ~ ind, m, toString)[-1]
```

**4) data.table** Note that in a comment below that @Uwe has provided a data.table version of the approach in (2) and (3) which is to convert to long form, join and convert back.

**Note:** Inputs in reproducible form:

```
Lines1 <- "
letter_strings
abc, def, ghi, jkl
mno, pqr
stu, vw, xyz"
DF1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, sep = ";")

Lines2 <- "
letter_strings code
abc YES
def NO
ghi MAYBE
jkl SURE
mno PERHAPS
pqr ALWAYS
stu NEVER
vw NOGO
xyz ABSENT"
DF2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is perfect for what I need!

Comment: In case you want to add a `data.table` version of *reshape to long, join, reshape back to wide*: `library(data.table); setDT(DF1); setDT(DF2); DF2[DF1[, rn := .I][, strsplit(letter_strings, ", ", fixed = TRUE), by = rn], on = .(letter_strings = V1)][, lapply(.SD, toString), by = rn][, -"rn"]`

Answer (score 0):

If there are not too many letter strings,  you can do this with `gsub` in a loop.

```
Temp = letter_strings
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    Temp = gsub(df$letter_strings[i], df$code[i], Temp) }
Temp
[1] "YES, NO, MAYBE, SURE" "PERHAPS, ALWAYS"      "NEVER, NOGO, ABSENT"
```